# Speed up this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query which is getting slower and slower because there are more and more records in my table. So I'm trying to speed things up.

Database size:
Records: 1,200,000
Data    22,9    MiB
Index   46,8    MiB
Total   69,7    MiB

The purpose of the query is counting the number of records that exist that match the conditions. The conditions are a date (current date) and a status number. See query below:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM
  order_process
WHERE
  DATE(datetime) = CURDATE() AND
  status = '7';
```

At the moment, this query is taking 800ms. And I need to run this query multiple times with different dates. These are all in the same script so script execution is going over the 3 seconds at the moment. How can I speed this up?

What have I already done:

- Created indexes (Index on `status` and `datetime` both don't speed up the query).
- Tested InnoDB engine (which is slower, mostly reading on this table)

To make it complete, below the current table setup.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_process` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `remark` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `orderid` (`order_id`),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Is there no index on status?

Comment: I tried that as wel, but no difference.

Comment: `DATE(datetime) = CURDATE()` can not use index you need to use as `datetime >= concat(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') and datetime <= concat(CURDATE(),' 23:59:59')` and also index on `status`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, Wooh!!! Just in 9 ms now! Now I need to do the same this for yesterday and last week.

Comment: Yes when you use date function on a timestamp/datetime column and even if the column is indexed it can't use the index. So you need to choose other alternative for this.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I think you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `date()` function on a timestamp/datetime column and even if the column is indexed it can't use the index

So you need to construct the query as

```
where
datetime >= concat(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') 
and datetime <= concat(CURDATE(),' 23:59:59')
and status = '7'
```

Comment: I prefer `datetime >= CURDATE() AND datetime < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`;